# Removing loading screen after site loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made a loading screen in HTML and CSS, but I am very new to JavaScript and I would like to make the loading screen vanish when the page is loaded. How do I do it in JS? Here is my code:

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #02171C;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dissaper {
  animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
}

.ring {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: ring 1.5s linear infinite;
}

.ring:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6497373b;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span {
  color: #649737;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="ring"></div>
  <span class="isLoaded">LOADING...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: First class name is disappearing.

Comment: Please proof read your question as your first listed class in your CSS code cuts off the top part of that section. Also you are tagging javascript yet there is no JS code in your question. Have you tried using javascript to listen for a loading event and then running a callback method to change your loader?

Answer (score 0):

Using your CSS and HTML here is an example of how to hide the `.loader` div once the window has fully loaded using JS.

In my example i've changed `.loader` div class to `#loader` div ID for easier javascript.

I've also used `transition` CSS instead of `animation` CSS on the `#loader` div, which runs when `.disappear` class is added.

Here is jsfiddle version to... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/z2dqe8jp/3/

See comments in JS and snippet console logs so you know JS timings with `transition` CSS, and when the `#loader` is removed.

```js
// our loader div by id (not class)
let loader = document.getElementById('loader');

// on window loaded
window.onload = (event) => {

  console.log('window loaded, and wait 3 secs for example #loader div to fade out');

  // for demo example 3 second delay for page load
  setTimeout(function() {

    // add .disappear class to #loader div
    loader.classList.add("disappear");

    console.log('.disappear class added to #loader element');

    // after 1 second css transition opacity .disappear has completed
    // plus an extra 250 milliseconds so not to remove #loader before transition is complete
    setTimeout(function() {

      // remove #loader element from DOM entirely
      loader.remove();

      console.log('#loader div element removed from DOM');

    // 1 second + 250 milliseconds delay
    }, 1250);

  // 3 seconds delay
  }, 3000);

};
```

```css
 #loader {
   position: fixed;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   align-self: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: #02171C;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   /* 1 second opacity ease transition */
   transition: opacity 1s ease;
 }

 .disappear {
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
 }

 .ring {
   position: absolute;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   animation: ring 1.5s linear infinite;
 }

 .ring:before {
   position: absolute;
   content: '';
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6497373b;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }

 span {
   color: #649737;
   font-size: 20px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   line-height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div class="ring"></div>
  <span class="isLoaded">LOADING...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the document loading is complete then:

1- remove the element. or
2- hide the element.

I added 1 second but you can remove it if you want.

comment `remove` then uncomment `hide` to see how it works then decide which one is suitable for you.

```js
// remove 
if (document.readyState = "complete") {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("loader").remove();
    }, 1000);
}

// OR

//  hide 
if (document.readyState = "complete") {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #02171C;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .dissaper {
    animation: fadeOut 1s forwards;
  }
  
  .ring {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: ring 1.5s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .ring:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6497373b;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  span {
    color: #649737;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="loader" id="loader">
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <span class="isLoaded">LOADING...</span>
  </div>
```